# How to run docker with current host user, when users are managed with Linux NIS (Network Information Service)

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, nis

I want to run the docker with my host account,

Normally I would do it with:

```
#!/bin/bash
user_home="${HOME:-"$(eval echo "~$(whoami)")"}"

docker run -it --rm \
  --env "USER=$(whoami)" \
  -u $(id -u ${USER}):$(id -g ${USER}) \
  --volume "${user_home}:${user_home}":ro \
  --volume /etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro \
  --volume /etc/group:/etc/group:ro \
  "ubuntu" /bin/bash
```

But now I need to do it on a PC that manages users with NIS (network information services)
My user is not present in the /etc/passwd

What would be the best direction?
Is it to somehow export users from NIS to some file and map it to /etc/passwd?

Comment: If you need host files and host users, an isolation environment like Docker probably isn't a good technical match for you.  Run the process directly on the host and you won't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're running Docker from a script, you can add some automation to extract the necessary information to a temporary file. Something like this:

```
getent passwd $(id -un) > /tmp/passwd.docker
getent group  $(id -gn) > /tmp/group.docker
```

The `getent` command looks up information in whatever directory sources are configured on your system, so it will pull information from NIS.

You can then mount `/tmp/passwd.docker` and `/tmp/group.docker` into your container.

Alternately, you can just generate the information you need, since all you really care about is the uid and username:

```
cat > /tmp/docker.passwd <<EOF
$LOGNAME:x:$(id -u):$(id -g):fake entry:$HOME:/bin/bash
EOF
```

Etc.

Comment: This worked, thanks     --volume /tmp/passwd.docker:/etc/passwd:ro   --volume /tmp/group.docker:/etc/group:ro